# Display ImageView in android studio using path of images stored in server

Tags: android, phpmyadmin

I want to display ImageView in android studio by using path image stored in my server"WAMP" this folder is in (/WWW/Images)

Comment: Are your images reachable by browser?

Comment: use library Picasso or Glide or Fresco.. easy to implement

Comment: Sam .. picasso library i found how to load image with image link from browser .. can i use it in my case ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using Glide (https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

According to its documentation:

```
    // For a simple view:
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

  GlideApp.with(this).load("http://your_url").into(imageView);
}
```